External Monitor not Seen on Dell 7450 and Ubuntu 22.04
External Monitor not Seen on Dell 7450 and Ubuntu 22.04
Link tried but no success.
Ubuntu 22.04 : No display signal from device
Would 24.04 work?
Please advise.
Many thanks
Marcelo

We don't have access to your hardware. So, please try Ubuntu 24.04 using a USB drive (without installing), and check it if works. If it works, that's great, go ahead with the installation. Otherwise, let us know that 24.04 does not work either, and someone may be able to help you with debugging
